# Making an indicator which determines the MACD values, and when MACD value is above the previous bar of MACD value, it gives a positive signal

Tags: pine-script

I would like to make a signal indicator which determines the MACD values and when "MacdValNHist" is above the "PreviousCandleMacdValNHist" giving a positive signal.
I know how to have the last value, but I don't know how to extract the MACD value of the provious bar to comphere it with the current bar MACD.
Here it's the code:

```
Fast=input(10, title="Fast")
Normal=input(40, title="Normal")
Slow=input(72, title="Slow")

[MacdValFLine, MacdValSSig, MacdValNHist] = ta.macd(close, Fast, Slow, Normal)
NMACDStatus = string(na)
var LblMacdNormalColor = color.white

if MacdValNHist > PreviousCandleMacdValNHist and MacdValNHist < 0
    NMACDStatus := "NormalSecurity:Confirmed:Accending"
    LblMacdNormalColor := color.green
else if...
```

I don't know how to make it, please help. If it's something about series and bar-index I should tell yoou that I'm very new to pine and I don't know anything about them... If you write the whole code for me it would be easier for me to understand it...